# Which Inode Size for Files bigger than 60mb

Tags: raid6

I will create a new server and wondered about the I-node options default, news, large file and largefile4. I searched the net and found explanations about 256kb until 4mb for one I-node, but i cant conclude the average file size for one of this. I checked an old server which have an average of 64MB and another of over 120mb. should I use large file or largefile4 for the new raid6 on ext4